# Alternate option for SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, windows-server-2008, ssms

I am trying to install [SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express found here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b), but I am getting a win32 not an application error.

Is there another option for managing Windows SQL Server databases other than Visual Studio? I just have to be able to log in to the server and run some test SQL like:

`ALTER TABLE test ADD column VARCHAR(50)`

Can you run that query in Visual Studio? If so that would solve the problem too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the command line [`sqlcmd` utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

> The sqlcmd utility lets you enter Transact-SQL statements, system procedures, and script files at the command prompt, in Query Editor in SQLCMD mode, in a Windows script file or in an operating system (Cmd.exe) job step of a SQL Server Agent job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run ad-hoc queries to a SQL Server database from Visual Studio.

Find/create a Data Connection in Server Explorer, right-click, and choose New Query.

[image]